# Let $V$ be a vector-space over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ equipped with a semi-norm $|| \ ||$. Prove $| || u || - || v || | \le || u - v ||$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector-space over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ equipped with a semi-norm $|| \     ||$.

I want to prove $|  || u || - || v ||  | \le || u - v ||$ for all $u, v \in V$.

I have considered the inequality $||x|-|y|| \le |x -y|$ for all complex numbers (corollary of *triangle inequality*). However, how can I apply this ?

I don't see how to prove this from the definitions of a semi-norm.

Comment: Just mimic the proof of the scalar case.

Comment: How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\|{\bf u}\| = \|{\bf u} - {\bf v} + {\bf v}\|,$$ and use the triangle inequality.

Comment: What about the absolute value ?

Comment: Doing what I told you, we get the inequality without the absolute value. Now repeat it starting with $\bf v $ and remember that $\|{\bf u} - {\bf v}\| = \|{\bf v} - {\bf u}\|$. If $b \geq a $ and $b \geq -a$, then $b \geq |a|$.